# SQL Server : SELECT JSON Column in this JSON Structure

Tags: sql-server, json-query, json-value

I would like to know will it possible to select data from below JSON structure?

```
 [
    {
        "A": 6, 
        "Status": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 3, 
        "Status": 0
    },
    {
        "A": 6, 
        "Status": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 7, 
        "Status": 0
    }
]
```

According this [link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-json-in-sql-server-2016/), there is Property before the array/object.

```
"EmployeeInfo": {  
        "FirstName":"Jignesh",  
        "LastName":"Trivedi",  
        "Code":"CCEEDD",  
        "Addresses": [  
            { "Address":"Test 0", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"},  
            { "Address":"Test 1", "City":"Gandhinagar", "State":"Gujarat"}  
        ]  
    }
```

For example, (getting sample from above link), we see the query is started with property `EmployeeInfo` so that make query possible to get data in this query.

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(@JSONData, '$.EmployeeInfo.FirstName')
```

So I just can't figure out how could this be achieve from the structure provide above, anyone could point me to some sample code that will be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options to parse this JSON array:

- Using `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema once - to get the content of each item
- Using `OPENJSON()` twice - to get the index and the content of each item

JSON:

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max) = '
[
    {
        "A": 6, 
        "Status": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 3, 
        "Status": 0
    },
    {
        "A": 6, 
        "Status": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 7, 
        "Status": 0
    }
]'
```

Using `OPENJSON()` with explicit schema once:

```
SELECT A, Status
FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
   A int,
   Status int
)
```

Result:

```
A   Status
6   1
3   0
6   1
7   0
```

Using `OPENJSON()` twice:

```
SELECT 
   j1.[key] AS Index,
   j2.A, j2.Status
FROM OPENJSON(@json) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.[value]) WITH (
   A int,
   Status int
) j2
```

Result:

```
Index   A   Status
0       6   1
1       3   0
2       6   1
3       7   0
```

Of course, you can always access an array item by index:

```
SELECT 
   JSON_QUERY(@json, '$[0]') AS Item,
   JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0].A') AS A, 
   JSON_VALUE(@json, '$[0].Status') AS Status
```

Result:

```
Item                   A    Status
{"A": 6, "Status": 1}  6    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) =N'
[
    {
        "A": 6, 
        "Status": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 3, 
        "Status": 0
    },
    {
        "A": 6, 
        "Status": 1
    },
    {
        "A": 7, 
        "Status": 0
    }
]'

select * from openjson(@json) with (A       int,
                                    Status  int);
```

Output

```
A   Status
6   1
3   0
6   1
7   0
```